# Upgrade to 18.04 from 17.10

Tags: upgrade

When I attempt to upgrade Ubuntu from 17.10 to 18.04, the Update Manger says "Your computer is up-to-date."

Why isn't it detecting the new release?

Comment: Did you go through the troubleshooting section of https://askubuntu.com/a/110483/173287?

Comment: @karel It should be available from 17.10 already according to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_17.10.

Comment: I know on a server install you do not see the new version till the first point release.  Depending on your initial install you may not be able to see the upgrade till 18.04.1 drops.  If you really want the new shiney, then:

    make sure your system is fully up-to-date
    from a terminal run the command sudo do-release-upgrade -d

Comment: How are you trying to upgrade?

Answer (score 4):

`-d` is for development releases. Do not put that command-line [option] in the command.

If you want a fresh and stable 18.04 simply type:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Now press <kbd>enter</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait for some days (more like a week or two) before the Update Manager tells you.

If you don't want to wait so long you can use the following command:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

Make sure nothing is going to interupt this process.