# How do I upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04 using usb

Tags: boot, upgrade, usb

I tried to use the update manager but it says your computer is up to date.
[Upgrade to 18.04 from 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030953/upgrade-to-18-04-from-17-10)

So I downloaded The .ISO file for Ubuntu 18.04.

Then when I boot from USB there is no option to upgrade.Only to erase for new installation and to divide partition.

Comment: The Ubuntu 18.04 live DVD / .ISO contains no packages. But a compressed image of the authors OS install.

Comment: I would try again without the USB. Have you checked `do-release-upgrade -c`? https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu